# Python - Regroup string by prefix

Tags: python, data-science

I have a dataset with a company name column and I have to regroup them in company group.
For example:
Dell UK, Dell France, Dell US => Dell Group
The data is not clean and some cells might contain mistakes like dots, or mispelling.

I tried some things like fuzzy comparaisons but sometimes the group prefix is small like 3M Group and the end of name is longer.

Do you have some tracks for me ?

Thank you and sorry for my English

Data :

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import pprint
import re

df = pd.read_csv("data2.csv", nrows=100)
l =  list(df["SUPPLIER_NAME"])
#print(df["SUPPLIER_NAME"])
liste = []
for i in range(len(l)):
    liste2 = []
    liste2.append(l[i])
    for j in range(len(l)):
        if i!=j:
            if fuzz.partial_ratio(l[i], l[j])>60:
                liste2.append(l[j])
    liste.append(liste2)

pprint.pprint(liste)
```

```
SUPPLIER_NAME
Dell France
Dell UK
Del US
3M Italy
3M COMPANY
3M SCIENCE
3.M SPAIN
3 M 
MCDONALDS France
MC DONALDS COMPANY
MCDONALD'S INC.
```

OUTPUT :

```
[['Dell France', 'Dell UK', 'Del US', 'MCDONALDS France'],
 ['Dell UK', 'Dell France', 'Del US'],
 ['Del US', 'Dell France', 'Dell UK'],
 ['3M Italy', '3 M '],
 ['3M COMPANY', '3.M SPAIN', '3 M ', 'MC DONALDS COMPANY'],
 ['3M SCIENCE', '3.M SPAIN', '3 M '],
 ['3.M SPAIN', '3M COMPANY', '3M SCIENCE', '3 M '],
 ['3 M ', '3M Italy', '3M COMPANY', '3M SCIENCE', '3.M SPAIN'],
 ['MCDONALDS France', 'Dell France', 'MC DONALDS COMPANY', "MCDONALD'S INC."],
 ['MC DONALDS COMPANY', '3M COMPANY', 'MCDONALDS France', "MCDONALD'S INC."],
 ["MCDONALD'S INC.", 'MCDONALDS France', 'MC DONALDS COMPANY']]
```

Comment: Can you provide some examples and code you have tried?

Comment: @tst I tried this https://medium.com/@categitau/fuzzy-string-matching-in-python-68f240d910fe and this https://towardsdatascience.com/group-thousands-of-similar-spreadsheet-text-cells-in-seconds-2493b3ce6d8d
And those company names are confidentials so I can not publish them sorry

Comment: You can always create some example dataset for clarity and post your code and result running on this exxample code.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Pre-processing

Start with basic cleaning ie. removing special characters/ punctuation, lowering case, etc to achieve a basic normalization. Here you can use simple string functions like replace, lower, etc. Find [here](https://medium.com/@datamonsters/text-preprocessing-in-python-steps-tools-and-examples-bf025f872908) a medium blog on pre-processing for your reference.

### 2. Count Analysis

Extraction of corrects words using count frequencies ie. if a word occurs more than a certain frequency/ percentage add it to the correct word list.

***(You can iterate between the first two steps to refine pre-processing and achieve a proper list.)***

### 3. Spell Check

The next step could be using a custom dictionary to apply spell check ie. use the list made in step 2 as a base for spellcheck algorithm. There are various options available for spell check algorithms in python eg. [symspell](https://github.com/wolfgarbe/SymSpell), [pyspellchecker](https://github.com/barrust/pyspellchecker), etc.

### 4. Fuzzy Matching

Iteratively for each name find out the best fuzzy match from the list of companies (achieved in step 2). [fuzzy-wuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) is the best implementation in python that can be used here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
For the Count Analysis part, it will count a large amount of country (ie. Dell FRANCE, UK etc) and will appear as an important word or this is not what I want.

Comment: you will have to carry count analysis on single words

Comment: And in a case where I have the company 1&1 written ["1&1","1 & 1", "1& 1"] and other companies starting by a 1 and a space ?